# Apache configuration and redirects in Azure Linux Web Apps

Tags: azure, configuration, apache2, azure-web-app-service

I have a Linux Web App running on Azure with a top-level domain. I want to redirect all traffic coming from mydomain.com to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) (because the free TLS certificate Azure offers only works for non-naked domain names for some reason).
As far as I see this, Apache is the default web server on Linux Web Apps. Unfortunately, it seems I can't just add a Redirect rule in the Apache config files because - I quote: "Any data outside '/home' is not persisted".

Is there any way to do this without having to deal with the redirect in the client application? (e.g. using PHPs `header()` function)?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach for PaaS Web Apps is to use an .htaccess file but it sounds like you don't want to deal with a redirect in the client application.

I can think of two other possibilities for you:

1. Use Web App Linux Containers
2. [Use Azure Frontdoor URL redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect)

Comment: I tried to add a .htaccess into /home/site/wwwroot with the following content, but it has no effect (no redirect to www)

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]